# How to properly do a case insensitive search in Java / Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I got a warning from Atlas Mongo saying:

> Do not use the $regex operator when using a case-insensitive index for
> your query. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and
> cannot utilize case-insensitive indexes. Instead, we recommend Atlas
> Search queries that use the $search aggregation pipeline stage.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/schema-suggestions/case-insensitive-regex/

In my Java code i'm using this:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
...
criteria.and("search").regex(data.getText(), "i"); // i means case-insensitive
...
return Query.query(criteria);
```

Obviously this is slow performance as I get a warning. How to I apply the collation?

What is the best performance approach for this so I remove the `i` option from the regex?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to query data with case-insensitive option is using text index and search operator instead of regex

Create index-case-insensitive for fields you want to query:

```
TextIndexDefinition textIndex = new TextIndexDefinitionBuilder()
  .onField("title", 2F)
  .onField("content")
  .build();

MongoTemplate template = … // obtain MongoTemplate
template.indexOps(CookingRecipe.class).ensureIndex(textIndex);
```

Then use text index to query data:

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
  .matchingAny("coffee", "cake");

Query query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria)
  .sortByScore()
  .with(new PageRequest(0, 5)); //top 5 documents matching “coffee” or “cake”
```

Kindly refer [$text $search your Documents with Spring Data MongoDB](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/17/text-search-your-documents-with-spring-data-mongodb) for more information